# Trying to map Student with Marks obtained

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I have the following tables:

```
Student(Student_ID(PK), FName, LName,...)
Subject_details(Subject_code(PK), Subject_Name)
Subjects_Enrolled(Student_ID,Subject_Code)
```

My question is:
Can i have table as the one below

```
Marks_Details(Student_ID,Subject_Code,Marks_Obtained)
```

Does that table break any rule of database or anything as such? My requirement is to have a table that maps the marks obtained by a student in a particular subject and this is what I've come up with. Is it correct or is there any other approach to do the same?
Please let me the know the reason if you're going to downvote.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data model looks fine.  Your simply setting up a Many To Many relationship with some additional information (marks) contained in each record.

One suggestion would be to rename the `Subject_Details` table to `Subject`.  I think this verbiage makes the relationship more clear.

Another suggestion would be to rename `Subjects_Enrolled` to `Enrollment` and just add the `Marks_Obtained` column to this table.  This would eliminate the need for `Marks_Details` since the two tables basically contain the same information.  Why store and maintain this data twice?  The idea would be to insert a record into `Enrollment` when a student enrolls within a course and then to update the `Marks_Obtained` column at a later date when the course is completed.

Comment: Agreed on the naming. Same goes for `Marks_Details`/`Marks`. Convention is to make database table names plural nouns. This would result in tables `Students`, `Subjects`, `Enrollments`, `Marks`

Comment: @Johanneke I was always taught to make table names singular.  But its all a matter of preference.

Comment: Ok, well, that might be a matter of personal preference. But nouns are pretty much always the way to go for table names, whether you use singular or plural.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox I actually thought of asking about the same thing.

Comment: @Johanneke Completely agree about nouns.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea doesn't "break any rule of database". I'd actually say it's pretty much the standard way of storing this data.

I would recommend to give the `Marks_Details` table a separate primary key, and maybe a date field. If a student wants to retake the subject, do you want the new data to override the old, or do you want to keep it both? It's up to you really.

Comment: What would be a possible primary key for the `Marks_Details` table?

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj You could use a surrogate key based off of a sequence or autonumber.  As a developer I put these on everything, DBAs don't always agree.

Comment: Well, as it is now, the combination of `Subject_code` and `Student_ID` might be a primary key, unless, as I pointed out, you want students to retake the subject and keep a history of their previous marks. I'd just use a generated id.

Comment: What @KevinBowersox said :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help guys. Appreciated! :)